# ZF2 setObject expects an object argument received ""

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have problem with bind() form. Am geting this error when i call bind in my editAction.
The error is:

**Zend\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException**

**File:**

```
/var/www/html/zf/zf-local/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Form/Fieldset.php:439
```

**Message:**

```
Zend\Form\Fieldset::setObject expects an object argument; received ""
```

**Stack trace:**

```
#0 /var/www/html/zf/zf-local/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Form/Form.php(271): Zend\Form\Fieldset->setObject(NULL)
#1 /var/www/html/zf/zf-local/module/Phonebook/src/Phonebook/Controller/PhonebookController.php(123): Zend\Form\Form->bind(NULL)
#2 /var/www/html/zf/zf-local/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(83): Phonebook\Controller\PhonebookController->editAction()
#3 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#4 /var/www/html/zf/zf-local/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 /var/www/html/zf/zf-local/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/html/zf/zf-local/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#7 /var/www/html/zf/zf-local/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#8 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /var/www/html/zf/zf-local/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 /var/www/html/zf/zf-local/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 /var/www/html/zf/zf-local/vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(309): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 /var/www/html/zf/zf-local/public/index.php(12): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#13 {main}
```

When i remove bind() all successfull executed but when i call form->bind am geting this error. I read doc and again the some.

My Edit Action is :

```
    /**
     * Edit Action
     */
 public function editAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
        if (!$id) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('phonebook', array(
                'action' => 'add'
            ));
        }

        // Get the Phonebook with the specified id.  An exception is thrown
        // if it cannot be found, in which case go to the index page.
        try {
            $phonebook = $this->getPhonebookTable()->getPhonebookItem($id);
        }
        catch (\Exception $ex) {
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('phonebook', array(
                'action' => 'index'
            ));
        }

        $form  = new PhonebookForm();
        $form->bind($phonebook);
        $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Edit');

        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()) {

            $form->setInputFilter($phonebook->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

            if ($form->isValid()) {

                $this->getPhonebookTable()->saveItem($phonebook);

                // Redirect to list of albums
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('phonebook');
            }
        }

        return array(
            'id' => $id,
            'form' => $form,
        );
    }
```

Debug **$phonebook** :

```
object(Phonebook\Model\Phonebook)[254]
  protected 'filter' => null
  public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'firstname' => string 'Ivan' (length=4)
  public 'lastname' => string 'Stojkovic' (length=11)
  public 'homephone' => string '0616278054' (length=10)
  public 'workphone' => string '013351456' (length=9)
  public 'company' => string 'Delix' (length=5)
  public 'email' => string 'office.stojmenovic@gmail.com' (length=28)
  public 'address' => string 'Voislava Ilica 8' (length=16)
  public 'city' => string 'Pancevo' (length=7)
  public 'fax' => string '21565486' (length=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `$phonebook` variable is null. So your `getPhonebookItem()` method does not seem to throw an exception as it should if no record is found.

Comment: -1.  var_dump return object with value. My `$phonebook` variable hold `(int)` id (uri segment and my model pass him. Problem is in `bind()`

Comment: Did you paste the right stack trace then ? Because it says otherwise : `Zend\Form\Form->bind(NULL)`.

Comment: Yeah i paste right stack. When i remove `$form->bind()` all is successfull rendered but whitout fields value. I dont know what is the problem. I debug `$phonebook`check update to see `>>output`

Answer (score 0):

Please look at your getPhonebookItem function, may be you nothing return.
You must return some $row.

like this...

```
$row = $rowset->current();

if(!$row) {
    throw new \Exception("Article #$id not found");
}
return $row; //!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in my situation was when I had attempted to retrieve an entity using Doctrine's Entity Manager and it returned null. I then passed a null/false value to $form->bind():

```
    $form->bind( $requestEntity );
```

This generated the error.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same error in a project that I developed using Doctrine.  With Doctrine, the equivalent to your

```
$phonebook = $this->getPhonebookTable()->getPhonebookItem($id);
```

might be something like

```
$phonebook = $this->getEntityManager()->find('PhonebookModule\Entity\Phonebook', $id);
```

My forms worked until I had the need to select a row from the database using a different column.  Instead of

```
public function editAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);

        // ...

            $phonebook = $this->getEntityManager()->find('PhonebookModule\Entity\Phonebook', $id);

            // ...
```

I needed something like

```
public function editAction()
    {
        $firstname = $this->params()->fromRoute('firstname', 0);

        // ...

            $phonebook = $this->getEntityManager()->find('PhonebookModule\Entity\Phonebook', $firstname);

            // ...
```

While I employed the same strategy in both methods, the latter caused the `setObject expects an object argument received “”` error.  After a lot of blood, sweat and tears, I eventually found that the function for populating the `$phonebook` variable wasn’t working.  In Doctrine, the `find(`) function only works if the column parameter is for a column that has been set as the id for the dataset in the entity.  If you want to select a row based upon a different column you have to use `findBy()` or `findOneBy()`.  In other words, if `$id` has been named as the id for the dataset in the entity, then

```
// this works:
$phonebook = $this->getEntityManager()->find('PhonebookModule\Entity\Phonebook', $id);

// this doesn’t work:     
$phonebook = $this->getEntityManager()->find('PhonebookModule\Entity\Phonebook', $firstname);

// this works:
$phonebook = $this->getEntityManager()->findOneBy('PhonebookModule\Entity\Phonebook', $firstname);
```

Although our code is different, perhaps my experience can help isolate your problem: the data DOES exist in the data model; but, for whatever reason, the function to put that data into the variable isn’t working.